# HibernateSearch ClassBridge - sorting and faceting not working with HS 5.5.1

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, lucene, hibernate-search

*I posted this a while ago in the hibernate search forum and got no response, so trying again in stackoverflow...*

Since migrating from HS 4.5.1 to HS 5.5.1 we have problems with sorting and faceting.

All our indexing is done using a class bridge which calls a CDI-Bean to do the actual indexing. In our system the configuration which fields are indexed is dynamic and can change at runtime, so we cannot use HS-annotations.

Sorting: we would like to take advantage of lucene's new sorting features using docvalues. We tried to add interface `MetadataProvidingFieldBridge` to the class bridge to provide the information which fields are sort fields, but at the time when the class bridge is initalized (when jboss is booting) the CDI-bean is not yet available.

**Question 1:** Is there a way to re-initialize the HS-`SearchIntegrator` at a later time, when the CDI-bean is available or when our index configuration has changed?
For the time being HS falls back to using the `UninvertingReader` for dealing with the sort fields without docvalues.

**Question 2**: Is this going to be supported in the future? How "bad" is it performancewise to use `UninvertingReader`?

With faceting we face a similar problem, we cannot use `@Facet`-annotation because the configuration is dynamic. For the time being we use lucene's faceting API directly.

**Question 3**: Is there a plan in HS to add faceting-information via a class bridge in the near future, similar to `MetadataProvidingFieldBridge`? Is the class bridge going to be supported by Hibernate Search in the future?

Code of the ClassBridge:

```
public class FtiClassBridgeCE implements FieldBridge, MetadataProvidingFieldBridge
{
@Override
public void set(String fieldName, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions options)
{
    if( !(value instanceof ComplexEntity))
        return; // ignore

    ComplexEntity object = (ComplexEntity)value;
    // FtiService does the actual indexing by adding fields to given document
    Configuration.service( FtiService.class).setIndexData( object, new FtiDocumentHS( document, options));
}

/*
 * This method is called in startup process of JBoss (Wildfly10) when initializing the persistence context. At that
 * time the CDI-Beans are not yet available resulting in a NullPointerException.
 * 
 * @see org.hibernate.search.bridge.MetadataProvidingFieldBridge#configureFieldMetadata(java.lang.String,
 * org.hibernate.search.bridge.spi.FieldMetadataBuilder)
 */
public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder)
{
    try
    {
        // FtiService is a CDI bean which is obtained from BeanManager via our Configuration-class
        // FtiSearchConfig stores information which fields should be added to lucene index and how they map to
        // ComplexEntity's data
        for( FtiSearchConfig config : Configuration.service( FtiService.class).getAllConfigurations())
        {
            for( FtiSearchField ftiSearchField : config.getSortFields())
            {
                builder.field( ftiSearchField.getNameForSort( null), hsSortType( ftiSearchField.getFieldDataType())).sortable( true);
            }
        }
    }
    catch( Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // catch the NPE thrown at JBoss boot time
    }

}

private FieldType hsSortType(FtiFieldDataType fieldDataType)
{
    switch( fieldDataType)
    {
    case DATE:
        return FieldType.LONG;
    case NUMERIC:
        return FieldType.INTEGER;
    case PRICE:
        return FieldType.DOUBLE;
    default:
        return FieldType.STRING;
    }
}
```

In the `@PostConstruct`-Method of the CDI-Bean I tried to reinitialized the HS SearchIntegrator like this but it did not call again the method `FtiClassBridgeCE.configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder)`.

```
    @PostConstruct
protected void initialize() throws ConfigurationException
{
    initSearchConfig();
    initializeHSSearch();
}

private void initializeHSSearch()
{
    FullTextEntityManager ftEM = ftidx().getFullTextEM();
    SearchIntegrator si = ftEM.getSearchFactory().unwrap( SearchIntegrator.class);
    SearchIntegratorBuilder sb = new SearchIntegratorBuilder().currentSearchIntegrator( si);
    sb.buildSearchIntegrator();
}
```

Which is the right way to do this or is there no way to reinitialize the SearchIntegrator?

Stacktrace of the Exception that is thrown at JBoss boot time when initializing HS SearchIntegrator:

```
13:33:12,656 INFO  [jpa] (ServerService Thread) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'mc.ear/web.war#mc'
13:33:16,219 INFO  [Dialect] (ServerService Thread) HHH000400: Using dialect: mc.core.system.util.db.SQLServerDialect
13:33:16,996 INFO  [EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread) Envers integration enabled? : true
13:33:23,864 INFO  [UpdateTimestampsCache] (ServerService Thread) HHH000250: Starting update timestamps cache at region: mc.ear/web.war#mc.org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache
13:33:25,675 INFO  [StandardQueryCache] (ServerService Thread) HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: mc.ear/web.war#mc.org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache
13:33:27,529 INFO  [Version] (ServerService Thread) HSEARCH000034: Hibernate Search 5.5.1.Final
 babysitten13:34:45,462 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread) java.lang.NullPointerException

13:34:45,463 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.<init>(BeanManagerProxy.java:74)

13:34:45,463 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldProvider$CdiImpl.getBeanManager(WeldProvider.java:95)

13:34:45,463 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldProvider$CdiImpl.getBeanManager(WeldProvider.java:73)

13:34:45,463 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at mc.core.service.configuration.WorkerFactory.lookupBM(WorkerFactory.java:42)

13:34:45,464 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at mc.core.service.configuration.WorkerFactory.createService(WorkerFactory.java:28)

13:34:45,464 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at mc.core.service.configuration.Configuration.service(Configuration.java:27)

13:34:45,464 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at mc.core.service.ftindex.hs.FtiClassBridgeCE.configureFieldMetadata(FtiClassBridgeCE.java:63)

13:34:45,464 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.AnnotationMetadataProvider.getSortableFieldNames(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:1751)

13:34:45,464 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.AnnotationMetadataProvider.bindClassBridgeAnnotation(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:621)

13:34:45,464 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.AnnotationMetadataProvider.bindClassBridgeAnnotation(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:593)

13:34:45,465 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.AnnotationMetadataProvider.initializeClassLevelAnnotations(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:546)

13:34:45,465 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.AnnotationMetadataProvider.initializeClass(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:430)

13:34:45,465 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.AnnotationMetadataProvider.getTypeMetadataFor(AnnotationMetadataProvider.java:130)

13:34:45,465 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:373)

13:34:45,466 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:199)

13:34:45,466 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:117)

13:34:45,467 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:75)

13:34:45,473 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)

13:34:45,473 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:530)

13:34:45,473 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.__build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)

13:34:45,474 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java)

13:34:45,474 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)

13:34:45,474 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.__build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)

13:34:45,474 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java)

13:34:45,474 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread)  at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
```

Comment: 3 Questions in one, no code to try it out. Hm. I'd vote for "Too broad", if I could - which I cannot as it is a bounty :) No offence intended. You should try to isolate your three questions - one questions on its own each - fill them with code we can run, probably host a small github project so that your problem gets reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The first question is the one of primary interest and an acceptable answer to this would certainly be bounty worthy :-) The second and third questions stem from our impression that the class bridge is no longer being actively developed and we would like guidance regarding whether we can (and should!) continue investing resources into maintaining our implementation based on this or start looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: Comment from this issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1316 might provide more insight about the internal state of this in HS: "I think the rub here is that ClassBridge instances are created when the metadata is built (at startup). I think it wold help if the creation of the bridges would be delayed until first use where it would be instantiated and then cached. This would of course require a fair bit of refactoring." https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1316?focusedCommentId=74831&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-74831